# Convert MongoDB object from updateOne into PHP array

Tags: php, mongodb

My output in PHP from a var_dump() shows the result of a updateOne MongoDB command to a collection:

```
object(MongoDB\UpdateResult)#136 (2) {  
    ["writeResult":"MongoDB\UpdateResult":private] => object(MongoDB\Driver\WriteResult)#135 (9) { 
        ["nInserted"]=> int(0) 
        ["nMatched"]=> int(0) 
        ["nModified"]=> int(0) 
        "nRemoved"]=> int(0) 
        ["nUpserted"]=> int(0) 
        ["upsertedIds"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["writeErrors"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["writeConcernError"]=> NULL 
        ["writeConcern"]=> array(4) { 
            ["w"]=> NULL 
            ["wmajority"]=> bool(false) 
            ["wtimeout"]=> int(0) 
            ["journal"]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
    ["isAcknowledged":"MongoDB\UpdateResult":private]=> bool(true) 
}
```

My question is, how do I convert this into PHP and access the value for "nMatched" and "nInserted"?

Comment: According to http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/class-MongoDB.UpdateResult.html there's a method called `getMatchedCount` to get the `nMatched` value, however there does not seem to be an equivalent one for `nInserted`, which probably makes sense since this is an `UpdateResult` and would only have modified values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the returned object directly.
For accessing matched you can do:

```
$result->getMatchedCount();
```

adn for the inserted:

```
$result->getUpsertedCount();
```

This is the right and easiest way.
You can use this as a reference http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/class-MongoDB.UpdateResult.html